# Why While Loop does not work in my program?

Tags: python-3.x, function, sorting, while-loop

The assignment is to create a program that allows user to enter friend's name and phone number then print out contact list sorted by last name. Also to use function.

My problem is it only asks the user to make one action and then it just ask for details right away. It should ask the user to choose another action. Either to exit, add contact, show contacts or sort contacts.

```py
def menu():
  '''Display Menu'''
  print(
    """

    Contact Lists

    0 - Exit
    1 - Show Contacts
    2 - Add Contacts
    3 - Sort Contacts
    """
    )

def ask():
  user = None
  user = input("Action: ")
  print()
  return user

def main():
  menu()
  action = ask()
  names = []

  while action != 0:
    if action == "0":
      print("Closing Contact Lists.")

    elif action == "1":
      print("Contact Lists: ")
      for name in names:
        print(name)
#setting a condition if user enter "2" it will let user add name, last name and phone number
    elif action == "2":
        name = input("Add contact's first name: ") #input 1
        last_name = input("Add contact's last name: ") #input 2
        contact_number = input("Add phone number for the contact name: ") #input 3
        entry = (last_name, name, contact_number)
        names.append(entry)

#setting a condition if user enter "3" it will sort contact list according to last names
    elif action == "3":
        entry.sort(reverse=True) #use of sort() to sort lists of by last names
        print(names)
    else:
        print("Invalid Action!") 

main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors in your code:

1. You should read user's input at the end of every loop.

Try to add `action = ask()` below your last `else` condition.

***edit***

code pieces:

```
#setting a condition if user enter "3" it will sort contact list according to last names
    elif action == "3":
        entry.sort(reverse=True) #use of sort() to sort lists of by last names
        print(names)
    else:
        print("Invalid Action!") 
    action = ask()
```

2. sort() should be performed on `names`(a list), not `entry`(a tuple)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by loop.append

Comment: Just a sentence, not python grammer.

Comment: `elif action == "3":
        names.sort(reverse=True) #use of sort() to sort lists of by last names
        print(names)
    else:
        print("Invalid Action!") 
        
    action = ask()

main()2

input("\nPress the enter key to exit.")` Now it does not stop asking for action

Comment: Sorry I am new here. Don't know the formatting yet.

Comment: Don't worry, I have added the code in my answer. Check if now you can get what you want

Comment: I was able to finish the program. I have to add 'break'. Thank you!